# DX11 triangle list is not rendering at all

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

I have a list of 4 verts loaded into a vert buffer, and an index loaded into a index buffer.

The issue I have is that while the LineList rendermode shows a quad just fine (see below) the TriangleList shows nothing (See below)

```cpp
void BLX::Model::load(std::filesystem::path path, Model* model, ID3D11Device* d3dDevice, ID3D11DeviceContext* d3dContext)
{
    // tmp: just making a quad
    float num = 0.5f;
    std::vector<BLX::Vertex> vertices = {
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-num, -num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f), },  // 0 = TL
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(num, -num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), },   // 1 = TR
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(num, num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f), }, // 2 = BR
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-num, num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f), },  // 3 = BL
    };

    // line list
    //std::vector<unsigned int> indices = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0 };

    // triangle list
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices = { 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2 };

    model->vertexCount = vertices.size();
    model->indexCount = indices.size();

    // Vertex Buffer

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd = {};
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0u;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0u;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(BLX::Vertex) * model->vertexCount;

    vbd.StructureByteStride = sizeof(BLX::Vertex);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vsd = {};
    vsd.pSysMem = &vertices[0];
    vsd.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vsd.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vsd, &model->vertexBuffer);

    /// Index Buffer
    
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd = {};
    ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned int) * model->indexCount;
    ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ibd.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA isd = {};
    isd.pSysMem = &indices[0];
    isd.SysMemPitch = 0;
    isd.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &isd, &model->indexBuffer);


    // IA = Input Assembly

    // pixel shader
    D3DReadFileToBlob(L"PixelShader2.cso", &model->pBlob);
    d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(model->pBlob->GetBufferPointer(), model->pBlob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &model->pPixelShader);

    // Vertex Shader
    D3DReadFileToBlob(L"VertexShader2.cso", &model->pBlob);
    d3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(model->pBlob->GetBufferPointer(), model->pBlob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &model->pVertexShader);

    const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        // "Position" correcponds to Vertex Shader Semantic Name
                    // semantic index
                        // data type format
                                                  // Input slot
                                                     // Aligned byte offset
                                                        // Input slot class
                                                                                     // Instance data step rate
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
    // needs vertex shader blob
    d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(ied, ARRAYSIZE(ied), model->pBlob->GetBufferPointer(), model->pBlob->GetBufferSize(), &model->pInputLayout);
}

void BLX::Model::render(ID3D11Device* d3dDevice, ID3D11DeviceContext* d3dContext, D3D11_VIEWPORT * vp)
{
    const UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    const UINT offset[] = { 0u, 0u };

    d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0u, 1u, vertexBuffer.GetAddressOf(), &stride, &offset[0]);
    d3dContext->IASetIndexBuffer(*indexBuffer.GetAddressOf(), DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, offset[1]);

    d3dContext->PSSetShader(pPixelShader.Get(), nullptr, 0u);
    d3dContext->VSSetShader(pVertexShader.Get(), nullptr, 0u);

    d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(pInputLayout.Get());

    d3dContext->RSSetViewports(1u, vp);

    //d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY::D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINELIST);
    d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY::D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    d3dContext->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);
}
```

When using the LineList index and topology:
[image]

When using the TriangleList index and topology:
[image]

But when I was doing this:

```cpp
    // tmp: just making a quad
    float num = 0.5f;
    std::vector<BLX::Vertex> vertices = {
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f), },
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(num, -num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), },
        BLX::Vertex { DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-num, -num, 0.0f), DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f), },
    };

    // triangle list
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

(everything else the exact same) I got this:
[image]

Just really curious what I'm not seeing or getting when trying to render two triangles to make up a quad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rectangle has indices organized in a clockwise manner, which are culled by the default rasterizer (since you do not specify one it culls clockwise primitives)

Your triangle vertices order was counter clockwise, so the primitive was not culled.

To solve it, two solutions:

- Change your indices order :

  ```
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices = { 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1 };
  ```
- Disable culling in the rasterizer state :

First create one [Rasterizer Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc)

```
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC raster_desc;
raster_desc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
raster_desc.CullMode= D3D11_CULL_NONE;
raster_desc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
raster_desc.DepthBias = 0;
raster_desc.DepthBiasClamp= 0.0f;
raster_desc.SlopeScaledDepthBias= 0.0f;
raster_desc.DepthClipEnable= true;
raster_desc.ScissorEnable= false;
raster_desc.MultisampleEnable= false;
raster_desc.AntialiasedLineEnable= false;
```

Then create a rasterizer state using your device:

```
   ID3D11RasterizerState* raster_state;
   HRESULT hr =d3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&raster_desc, &raster_state);
```

Before the draw, assign your rasterizer state to your context:

```
   d3dContext->RSSetState(raster_state);
```

Comment: This worked! To let you know where I wound up though: setting the indicies to reverse order and going CCW wind worked with FrontCounterclockwise set to false and CullMode set to CULL_BACK. I then brought back my original Clockwise index order and set FrontCounterclockwise to true, and that also now works too. I'm confused why this works though, according to the docs the default wind order is CW, why did I have to tell the RS State to be CW and then supply the verts in a CCW fashion and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Your two meshes, triangle and quad, have opposite triangle winding order. Here’s how.

[image]

[By default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc#remarks), D3D11 uses CullMode=Back and FrontCounterClockwise=FALSE.
This means it only renders front faces, and front face is defined as “when the vertices are counter-clockwise”.

As you see from the above illustration, your triangle indeed has counter-clockwise order, however both triangles of your quad are clockwise, GPU considers them as back faces and skips both.

You have many ways to fix, any of the following will do.

1. Reorder vertices in vertex buffer.
2. Flip triangles in index buffer to `{ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2 }`
3. Change rasterizer state to disable back face culling, `CullMode=D3D11_CULL_NONE`
4. Change rasterizer state to switch front face winding direction, `FrontCounterClockwise=TRUE`
5. Change matrix passed to vertex shader to include mirroring component, e.g. scale with vector `[ -1, 1, 1 ]` represents a mirror transform that flips X, this will flip winding order of the whole mesh.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and also did work.  To let you know where I wound up though: setting the indicies to reverse order and going CCW wind worked with FrontCounterclockwise set to false and CullMode set to CULL_BACK.  I then brought back my original Clockwise index order and set FrontCounterclockwise to true, and that also now works too.   I'm confused why this works though, according to the docs the default wind order is CW, why did I have to tell the RS State to be CW and then supply the verts in a CCW fashion and vice versa?